# Create repo with reusable CMake packages

Tags: cmake, package

I am creating a repository containing various C++/C/Qt components that can be easily reused in other projects. I am calling this "Base" repository.

In the end, I want to be able to include a components in a Qt style, like as it follows:

```
project(BaseLibsTest)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/base/install")
find_package(Base COMPONENTS Utils REQUIRED)

add_executable(BaseLibsTest main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(BaseLibsTest PRIVATE Base::Utils)
```

I want to use the workspace name "Base" to be protected agains components name collision. Project can link other components with the name "Utils" in this case.

The structure of the base repository looks like this:

```
libs/base:
│   BaseConfig.cmake.in
│   CMakeLists.txt
└───Utils
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │
    ├───include
    │   └───Utils
    │           Utils.h
    │
    └───src
            Utils.cpp
```

*CMakeLists.txt* and *BaseConfig.cmake.in* from the root of the base have the following content:

**CMakeLists.txt**:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(Base VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Base repository containing reusable packages")

# Optionally, set a custom install directory for the packages
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/install)

# Include subdirectories for each component
add_subdirectory(Utils)
# add_subdirectory(another_component) - Add other components if needed

####################################################################################

# Export configuration
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)

# Generate the package configuration file
configure_package_config_file(
        BaseConfig.cmake.in
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BaseConfig.cmake
        INSTALL_DESTINATION cmake
)

# Install the package configuration file
install(
        FILES ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/BaseConfig.cmake
        DESTINATION cmake
)
```

**BaseConfig.cmake.in**:

```
@PACKAGE_INIT@

# Optionally, you can set some variables here, such as additional dependencies
# set(BASE_UTILS_LIBRARIES Base::Utils)

# List of exported targets
set(BASE_TARGETS Base::Utils)

# Install the export group
install(EXPORT BaseConfig
    NAMESPACE Base::
    DESTINATION cmake
)
```

And finally, CMakeLists from Utils component:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Utils VERSION 1.0.0 DESCRIPTION "Basic utilities")

add_compile_definitions(IS_BUILT_AS_LIBRARY=1)

find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Core Network REQUIRED)

# Define the library target
add_library(Utils SHARED src/Utils.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Utils PRIVATE Qt::Core Qt::Network)

# Set the include directories for users of this library
target_include_directories(Utils PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>)

# Install rules
install(TARGETS Utils
        EXPORT UtilsConfig
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION include)

# Generate and install the package configuration
install(EXPORT UtilsConfig
        NAMESPACE Base::
        DESTINATION cmake)
```

Building base components is succeeding using command `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. && cmake --build . --target install` and folder `install` is created containing `BaseConfig.cmake` and `UtilsConfig.cmake`.

The problem is that Base::Utils component is not found when including the package as indicated in the first code sample. Error is the following:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: INSTALL(EXPORT) given unknown export "BaseConfig"
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (target_link_libraries):
  Target "BaseLibsTest" links to:

    Base::Utils

  but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:

    * There is a typo in the target name.
    * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
    * An ALIAS target is missing.



-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

It is able to find "Base" but cannot find "Base::Utils". Any hint why it is not found?

Comment: Why do you write `install(EXPORT BaseConfig...)` in the **config file** (`BaseConfig.cmake.in`)?? In that file you should include installed export files, like `include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/UtilsConfig.cmake")`. See e.g. [CMake documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-a-package-configuration-file) about creating packages.

Comment: You were right, after changing BaseConfig.cmake.in according to your indications, it works fine. Thanks